# SharePoint 2013 Event Receiver Assembly Error

Tags: sharepoint, .net-assembly

Sorry, my English is bad, but i will try to explain what i mean.

I made EventReceiver on Developer PC on VisualStudio 2012 and it's work on my developer's SharePoint2013 Server.

I made WSP packgage, deployed it to Client's SharePoint 2013 Server, activated feature and get an Error.

Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsService' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.900.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

How i understood it's SharePoint.Dll version is another, but i can't find this version and don't know where it's on clients server.

Comment: Was the error message returned by the server or displayed locally?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Error. I copied dll files and had the same Error. Installed Visual Studio on clinet Server and it didn't help. I think it's server configuration bad.

Answer (score 0):

To load SPDiagnosticsService, you need to ensure that your solution is deployed to the Farm.

To do check the settings, view the project properties, make sure **Sandboxed Solution** is set to False